# Скорость выборки в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно сделать ограничение на количество заявок с сайта от одного человека.
Для этого собираюсь писать в базу Время заявки, имэйл и телефон.
Каждый день в базе будет появляться 30-50 новых записей.
Насколько быстро будет выполняться выборка одной строки по имэйлу и телефону
из таблицы? От чего вообще зависит скорость? Не будет ли выборка длиться по 10 секунд?

Comment: проставите нормально индексы, настроите базу данных, составите правильные запросы и пожалуйста хоть сотни и тысячи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте подойдем практично к информации. 
Дата - имейл -телефон
Имейл и телефон штука не уникальная, дата уникальная. Надо ограничить количество заявок получается мы ищем по имейл и телефон. Ставим на это индекс (на оба поля одновременно - один). Получается что выборка у нас count(*) или count(id) или count(date) значит еще одно ограничение, больше чем n записей быть не может т.е. ограничены сверху. Ну пусть там будет хоть миллион - индексируем по уникальности давайте 2 таблицы сделаем и 2 запроса. И одну. Заполним миллионом записей по правилу и проверим нагрузку. Я не думаю что тут будет вообще какая-то проблемаю Дороже записать чем выбрать в данном случаи.

Comment: А как по индексу делать выборку, можете также в двух словах объяснить? :-) Сначала выбираем поле с нужным телефоном, затем получаем его индекс, и по индексу уже имэйл ищем?

Comment: @АнтонПетренко индекс вешается на определённые поля, и если оптимизатор запросов решает, что некий индекс поможет, он сам его применит (при условии, что он существует, конечно). Когда он терпит фиаско (а такое бывает), можно использовать совет `use index`, читайте документацию.

Answer (score 2):

Скорость зависит от наличия индексов и степени уникальности строк (для уникальных строк - существенно быстрее). Ну и телефон стоит хранить не в виде текста. 10 секунд точно не будет. Прирост 50 записей в день - это пыль дорог для современной БД.

Формально, здесь и SQL-база не нужна. Нужна свалка с поиском, и главное - автоуничтожением устаревших записей. Кэш, короче. Такой штуке и сотни тысяч запросов в секунду будут нипочем.

Comment: Допустим, через год - 50 000 записей. Это также будет пылью? :-)

Comment: Какой вообще диапазон в секундах возможен?